# Form validation in javascript using html

Tags: html

I have been learning Javascript using the thenewboston YouTube channel. In the form validation part I am getting the following error *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <form>
            Username: <input type="text"/>
            Password: <input type="password"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit!"/>
        </form>
        //length of a form is how many items do you have in it
        var x = document.forms[0].length
        document.write(x);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to take the form tag outside the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

The form shouldn't be in your script! Putting HTML code in a `<script>` element doesn't make sense.
For that, you are getting the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Here is your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
          Username: <input type="text"/>
          Password: <input type="password"/>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit!"/>
      </form>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          //length of a form is how many items do you have in it
          var x = document.forms[0].length
          document.write(x);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```